# Why does connected polyline (KML file) appear unconnect in arcmap as layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, kml, line

I created polygone in google earth and imported it to arcmap as layer. All things are OK but when I converted polygon to polyline, there some parts of polyline has not shown although its vertices appear?
How to fix this problem ? 
 [image: blue highlight of some part not appear]

[image: vertices of missing line are appear]

[image: Still missing]

Comment: WOW! I have never seen this before. Maybe the tip to you is draw a new polygon using the "trace" tool.

Comment: Trace tool is inactivate